# How to take medians of every row between two columns non-interatively?

Tags: r

I'm trying to do some summary statistics of a very large data set where I need to generate the median of each row of a dataframe containing 2 columns, and then storing it as a dataframe. I did it iteratively, but its taking way too long and crashing my system.

To avoid slow for loops I tried using mapply like so:

`Center_Point<-mapply(median, c(File$V2, File$V3))`

but it only returns the median of the individual values rather than the median of the rows shared by these two columns. Is there a way to do this with any of the apply functions, or should I just switch over to something faster like Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1`

```
apply(File[c('V2', 'V3')], 1, median, na.rm=TRUE)
```

---

The `Map/mapply` applies the function on the corresponding elements of `list` or `vector` etc.  As we have two `vectors`, we can specify those as input arguments and get the `median`.

```
mapply(median, File[,'V2'], File[,'V3'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider `rowMedians()` from the [matrixStats](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matrixStats/index.html) package

```
> m = matrix(rnorm(100000), ncol=2)
> identical(matrixStats::rowMedians(m), apply(m, 1, median))
[1] TRUE
> system.time(matrixStats::rowMedians(m))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.003   0.000   0.009 
> system.time(apply(m, 1, median))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.032   0.000   2.033
```